# How to create iterator without type names?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, std, c++03

For example I have a `std::map<int, string> _m;` and I want to iterate through it.
So I have to write something like this: `std::map<int, string>::iterator it = _m.begin()`.

The question is whether it is possible to create that iterator without using type names. Compiler knows the type of `_m` at the moment of creation of iterator, so why do I need to write those types myself?

UPDATE
I forgot to say that I've to use old C++ standard.

Comment: You cant do that unless you use C++11.  You can make a typedef so you don't have to type `std::map<int, string>::iterator` every time you need to make an iterator of the type.

Comment: "I've to use old C++ standard" - then you're missing out on a lot of good things. Including the ability to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're after the `auto` keyword:

```
auto it = _m.begin();
```

> Compiler knows the type of _m at the moment of creation of iterator, so why do I need to write those types myself?

Yes, this is the **exact** logic that lead to the introduction of `auto`.

If you cannot use C++11, you're stuck with things like `typedef`. The whole reason the new standard introduced `auto` is because of the exact problem you're facing - it's awkward to have to manually write out long type names all the time.

```
typedef std::map<int, string>::iterator map_itr;

map_itr it = _m.begin();
```

Comment: I'm sorry if forgot to say that I have to use old C++ standard

Comment: Then, no. The whole reason for introducing the `auto` keyword is that it was cumbersome to always type things like `std::map<int, string>::iterator it`. You're stuck with it unless you want to start typedef-ing it.

Comment: Yes I know about typedef syntax, but it does not solve this particular problem. If one day the definition of map veriable changes then we have to change typedef either. I was wondering whether there is some "old version of auto" or at least some dirty hacks to achieve this behaviour, but thank you for your help.

Comment: I suggest using non-member begin()/end()

(see this for explanation http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/)

Comment: @Incubbus ... which were only introduced in C++11, which the OP can't use.

Comment: @SkySurfer Then you're missusing `typedef` The `typedef` itself should be the source for truth on your type. Everything else should be using the typedef. If your type changes, you should be changing your `typedef`, nothing else. Otherwise, please, listen: I'm telling you, the entire reason C++11 introduced `auto` was to solve this problem. Obviously there was **no good solution** prior to this, or they wouldn't have added `auto` to the language. The solution you're after **is the `auto` keyword**, but you cannot use it, so stop asking for that exact solution. It doesn't exist prior to C++11.

Comment: @meagar I just wanted to hear all versions, i apologize for the disturbance.

Comment: Non-member begin/end can be easily backported to C++03 if they are needed, but in this case it doesn't seem it would be. "If one day the definition of map variable changes" --> if the new definition is still using a container, then ".begin()" and ".end()" will still be valid.

Answer (score 4):

Since you specify that you're locked back in time to C++98, then about the best you have is whatever black magic is behind BOOST_AUTO.

```
#include <boost/typeof/typeof.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
     std::map<int, std::string> m;
     BOOST_AUTO(it, m.begin());
}
```

BOOST_FOREACH was created as a similar thing for dealing with loops without having to specify iterator types.

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    // populate v...

    BOOST_FOREACH(int const &i, v)
    {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually it is possible by using template function:

```
template <typename ITERATORTYPE> void myfunc(ITERATORTYPE it) {
    //.. do whatever you want with your it
}
```

Then just invoke the template:

```
myfunc(_m.begin());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're stuck to C++03, there's no way to refer to the type without spelling it out if you *really* need it. The best you could do is introduce a `typedef` (or more) so that you only have to type the long type once:

```
typedef std::map<int, string> TypeOfM;
typedef TypeOfM::iterator MIterator;
TypeOfM _m;
```

However, when you use standard library algorithms, you don't have to name the iterators explicitly:

```
std::for_each(_m.begin(), _m.end(), /* a functor */);
```

If Boost is an option, and you really only want iteration, you could also use [Boost.Foreach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/foreach.html). Unfortunately, that would still need a typedef, because the `value_type` of `map` is a pair and thus contains a `,` which would trip up the preprocessor:

```
typedef std::pair<const int, string> Pair;
BOOST_FOREACH(const Pair &p, _m)
{
  // Do whatever you need
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're trying to iterate over it, you may try one of the `<algorithm>`s such as `std::for_each` and pass a function

Answer (score 0):

The best general way is by using C++11's `auto` keyword as type. In later versions this can be done even better with range-bsed loops without any type information.

```
for (it : _m) {
    /* ... */
}
```

If you are stuck to old versions the only way to shorten the typename would be to create a template. This might make it more complex than writing the name, though. Something along those lines:

```
template <typename T> 
void do_foo(T it, T end) {
    for (; it < end; ++it) {
        /* ... */
    }
 }

 do_foo(_m.begin(), _m.end());
```

If wrapping your algorithm isn't the way you can also use a typedef to shorten it, but then you still have to type the name once.

Comment: C++11 introduced both `auto` and range-based `for` loops. Your answer makes it sound as if the latter came later.